# Sqoop export into Aurora RDS is extreamly Slow

Tags: mysql, sqoop, hadoop2, amazon-emr, amazon-aurora

I am trying to export my 130GB data which is in 900 files from S3 to Auroa/MySql RDS.
I have 10 nodes cluster of `10r4.4xlarge` configuration .
And the Aurora is on

```
Aurora : db.r3.2xlarge 8 CPU, 61 GB RAM)
```

Also when i run my Sqoop command i can see 917 mappers are kicked off .
But the export is still very very slow .It takes more than 2 hours to load all data .

Here is my Sqoop command that i am trying to execute .

```
sqoop export \
--connect jdbc:mysql://a205067-pppp-ec2.abcd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/tprdb \
--username user \
--password Welcome12345 \
--table UniverseMaster \
--export-dir s3://205067-pppp-latest-new/output/processing/NextIteration/ \
--fields-terminated-by  '|' \
--num-mappers 1000 \
--direct \
-- --default-character-set=latin1
```

Is there any way i can improve Sqoop Export ?
I tried using records per transaction but still same result .

Please suggest..

Comment: Were you able to optimize this? If so, can you share how?

Answer (score 0):

You can export it in batches, also partitioning will help but there are more solutions exists. You can refer this HortonWorks link https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/70258/sqoop-performance-tuning.html to find more performance tuning methods.